# Font Awesome displays symbol for external link in Jekyll - How can I avoid this?

Tags: jekyll, font-awesome

At the moment I'm trying to integrate my social media presence on my homepage with jekyll and font awesome icons. However, with clickable FA icons unfortunately these ugly icons for external links (to the right of the respective icon) are inserted. Does anyone have an idea how to avoid this?

[image: This is how it currently looks like]

Comment: It seems that your Jekyll theme includes the additional font awesome icon (fa-external-link). Search the source code for it and create a template/snippet that is not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in the `/stylesheets` or `/_compass` folders for all the css or scss files and see if you find the culprit. I would suspect something like this:

```css
a[href^="http"]:after {
     content: " " url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAVklEQVR4Xn3PgQkAMQhDUXfqTu7kTtkpd5RA8AInfArtQ2iRXFWT2QedAfttj2FsPIOE1eCOlEuoWWjgzYaB/IkeGOrxXhqB+uA9Bfcm0lAZuh+YIeAD+cAqSz4kCMUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```